# Inserting rows with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, select, insert

**Structure**

1 table named: *scan*

2 columns named: *id*, and *date*

**Problem**

I have two working queries, a SELECT and then an INSERT which I would like to merge together creating a INSERT where the condition is equal to 0.

**Query 1**

Show '1' if the *latest* ID row in the database has scan date of today otherwise show '0' when no today's date is present.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(scan.date) AS datecheck
FROM scan
WHERE scan.id = (SELECT
    MAX(scan.id) AS datecheck
  FROM scan
  WHERE scan.date = CURDATE())
```

**Query 2**

If there is no entry for today, meaning a results of '0' then create a new row with ID+1 and the current date.

```
INSERT INTO `scan`(`id`, `date`) SELECT (MAX(id)+1), CURDATE() FROM scan;
```

I have been trying for hours now with no luck yet, I would be grateful if you can tell me where I am going wrong and let me know what the correct query is. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rephrasing your query it seems like you simply want to check if there's no row with today's date. It's a bit tricky to make it an conditional Insert:

```
INSERT INTO scan (id, date)
SELECT (MAX(id)+1), CURDATE()
FROM scan
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN scan.date = CURDATE() THEN 1 end) = 0;
```

To make it work even with an empty table change to `(COALESCE(MAX(id),0)+1)`

Answer (score 3):

#### Query 1

Show `1` if the *latest* ID row in the database has scan date of today otherwise show `0`.

Can be written more simply (and more efficiently):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN scan.date = CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS datecheck
FROM scan
ORDER BY scan.id DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

and (if we like obfuscation):

```
SELECT (scan.date = CURDATE()) AS datecheck
FROM scan
ORDER BY scan.id DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

#### Query 2

If the result of the previous query of `0`, then insert a new row with `ID + 1` and the current date.

```
INSERT INTO scan 
    (id, date) 
SELECT latest.id + 1, CURDATE() 
FROM 
  ( SELECT scan.id, scan.date
    FROM scan
    ORDER BY scan.id DESC
    LIMIT 1 
  ) AS latest
WHERE latest.date <> CURDATE() ;
```

---

**Note:** All the above queries check only the row with the **latest (highest) `id`** value. Your wording is ambiguous. There may be cases where a row with lower `id` has the curent date as `date` value. It's not clear what you want to happen in that case!

If you do want to check the highest date of the table, then you probably need to replace the `ORDER BY scan.id DESC` with `ORDER BY scan.date DESC`, which will check the **highest date** (and whether it's the current date).

If you want to check all the table for any rows with current date, then you need to replace that with `WHERE scan.date <= CURDATE() ORDER BY scan.date DESC`, which will check the whole table for any rows with current date.

Comment: And to state it explicitly, both queries will work only if the table has at least one row.